# Calling CMake function with list arguments

Tags: cmake, code-generation

I'm programming a c++ library that utilizes automatic code generation. I'm using the CMake command `add_custom_target()` to do so. As there are multiple separate parts of the library that will use code generation, I wanted to wrap this in a CMake function.

The problem is that when calling the function, the actual generator never triggers.

#### What I tried and it doesn't work

I'm defining this function...

```
function(setup_code_generation PART_NAME DEPENDENCIES HEADERS SOURCES)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT
            ${HEADERS}
            ${SOURCES}
        COMMAND
            python3 ${GENERATOR_INPUT_DIR}/${PART_NAME}/generator.py
            --input-files ${GENERATOR_INPUT_DIR}/${PART_NAME}
            --output-headers ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/header/${PART_NAME}
            --output-sources ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/source/${PART_NAME}
        COMMENT
            "Generating code for ${PART_NAME}"
        DEPENDS
           ${DEPENDENCIES}
        VERBATIM
    )
    set(MY_LIB_GENERATED_SOURCE ${MY_LIB_GENERATED_SOURCE}
        ${SOURCES}
    )
endfunction()
```

and call it like this

```
set(FOO_DEPENDENCIES
    ${GENERATOR_INPUT_DIR}/foo/generator.py
    ${GENERATOR_INPUT_DIR}/foo/specs.json
)

set(FOO_HEADERS
    ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/header/foo/foo_headerA.hpp
    ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/header/foo/foo_headerB.hpp
    ...
)

set(FOO_SOURCES
    ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/source/foo/foo_sourceA.cpp
    ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/source/foo/foo_sourceB.cpp
)

setup_code_generation(foo "${FOO_DEPENDENCIES}" "${FOO_HEADERS}" "${FOO_SOURCES}")
```

Running CMake appears to work, but when running Make it will eventually run in an error like

```
foo/foo_headerA.hpp: no such file or directory
```

cause by on of the regular files. I can also tell from the console output that the generator script is never run.

#### But what does work

If I replace the function setup and function call with something like this

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/header/foo/foo_headerA.hpp
        ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/header/foo/foo_headerB.hpp
        ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/header/foo/foo_sourceA.cpp
        ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/source/foo/foo_sourceB.cpp
    COMMAND
        python3 ${GENERATOR_INPUT_DIR}/foo/generator.py
        --input-files ${GENERATOR_INPUT_DIR}/foo
        --output-headers ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/header/foo
        --output-sources ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/source/foo
    DEPENDS
        ${GENERATOR_INPUT_DIR}/foo/generator.py
        ${GENERATOR_INPUT_DIR}/foo/specs.json
    VERBATIM
)
set(ENGINE_GENERATED_SOURCE ${ENGINE_GENERATED_SOURCE}
    ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/source/foo/foo_sourceA.cpp
    ${GENERATOR_OUTPUT_DIR}/source/foo/foo_sourceB.cpp
)
```

than it works like expected and the generator script is call before attempting to compile/parse anything that depends on the outputs. My suspicion is that `${HEADERS}` and `${SOURCES}` aren't untangled and combined how I expect them to, thus messing up the `OUTPUT` field.

This would be my fallback solution, but I want to be able to utilize CMake functions and I want to avoid writing repetitive code. It would be somewhat ironic, given that avoiding writing repetitive code is the primary reason why I want to auto-generate c++ code in the first place.

Comment: Typically with https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html

Comment: Your problem is not how to **pass** a list to the function, but how to **return** a list. Your setting of variable `MY_LIB_GENERATED_SOURCE` is visible only inside the function and lost upon the function's returns. You need to add PARENT_SCOPE option to that setting.